# Is it possible to reset to factory settings without USB Debug?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, sony-xperia

Is there any way to reset to factory settings without the USB debug? 
I have an Sony Xperia E3 model number D2203. The reason is I bought it 2 years ago and stopped using it 6 months after, but now I need it again. I can't get in cause I managed to put up a password I can't remember probably cause on an app or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [user manual](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=factory+reset+Sony+Xperia+E3&oq=factory+reset+Sony+Xperia+E3&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.6965j0j7&client=ms-android-xiaomi-rev2&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

> Power Off Your Sony Xperia E3.
>
> Press And Hold Volume up Key + Volume Down key + Power Key.
>
> Now You Will see a Android Robot on screen.
> Select ” Wipe Data / Factory Reset ” Option By Using Volume Key .